# jOOQ: MySQL "TEMPORARY TABLE" does not exist during transaction?

Tags: mysql, jooq

I have code like the following:

```kotlin
fun <T> withTempTableTxn(
    ctx: DSLContext,
    tempTableSelectAs: org.jooq.Select<*>,
    txnBlock: (DSLContext, org.jooq.Name) -> T,
): T {
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "_")

    val tempTableName = DSL.name("temp_table_$uuid")
    val createTempTable = DSL.createGlobalTemporaryTable(tempTableName).`as`(tempTableSelectAs)

    return ctx.transactionResult { txn ->
        txn.dsl().execute(createTempTable)
        val res = txnBlock(txn.dsl(), tempTableName)
        txn.dsl().execute(DSL.dropTemporaryTableIfExists(tempTableName))
        res
    }
}

private fun updateMutation(
    mutationRequest: MutationRequest,
    op: UpdateMutationOperation,
    ctx: DSLContext,
): MutationOperationResult {
    // The rows that the temporary table will be populated with
    val tempTableRows = DSL
        .selectFrom(DSL.table(DSL.name(op.table.value)))
        .where(/* ... */)

    return withTempTableTxn(ctx, tempTableRows) { txn, tempTableName ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

When this runs, it seems like the temporary table can't be found.

> **Note that if I replace `temporaryTable` with a regular table, it all works fine**

If I add an `.also { println(ctx.render(it)) }` to the `createTempTable`, we get:

```
Creating temp table:
create temporary table `temp_table_e2fd79a5_4589_41df_9972_8ff9b216300a`
as
select *
from `Chinook`.`Artist`
where `Artist`.`Name` = 'foobar'

13:48:02 ERROR traceId=, parentId=, spanId=, sampled= [io.ha.ap.ExceptionHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught exception: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update `temp_table_e2fd79a5_4589_41df_9972_8ff9b216300a`
set
  `Name` = 'foobar new'
where `temp_table_e2fd79a5_4589_41df_9972_8ff9b216300a`.`Name` = 'foobar'];
Table 'Chinook.temp_table_e2fd79a5_4589_41df_9972_8ff9b216300a' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Does your `txnBlock` work with the argument `txn: DSLContext`, or with the "outer" `ctx: DSLContext` value? Both are in scope, probably, and it's easy to use the wrong one.

Comment: Oh my *facepalm*, that was it. Boy do I feel stupid, thanks Lukas!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's happening behind the scenes here? It doesn't actually ever send the "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" if passed the wrong "ctx"?

Comment: It does execute `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, but in a different transaction, and thus probably in a different session, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html):

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name.

Other RDBMS have temporary tables whose meta data is shared between sessions / transactions, truncating only data on commit, but not in MySQL.

As far as jOOQ is concerned, the most likely explanation is that you're creating and dropping the table using `txn.dsl()` (transaction 1), but you're running your `txnBlock` using `ctx`, which is also in scope, but is running a different transaction. As such, it can't see your `txn`'s temporary tables.